# Point of sales defined

Tags: mysql, sql

I build an inventory and management stock + invoice
I have a table "invoice"

```
content: id 
customer_name
net_total
paid
due
ordre_date
```

I want to show all net_total for everyday, for week, and for months

I use this query

```
SELECT *, sum(net_total) as privé 
FROM invoice 
GROUP BY order_date
```

But it's don't show all net_total for each day

Comment: What do you mean " it doesn't show all net_total for each day"?  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m%d') AS order_day, sum(net_total) AS privé FROM invoice GROUP BY order_day ORDER by order_day
```

As order_date might be a timestamp with hour, minutes... and you want to group by just the day.

Comment: It's work i wanna to add searchbar who allow to search the net total of specific day . si i use this query " select  ordre_date as ordre_day, sum(net_total) as privé from invoice group by order_day  where order_day like  '%".$search."%'

Comment: I think the `where` goes always before a `group by`. If the answer works you could mark it as correct.